# What is the latest time a non-baseball sporting event has ever ended?

Tags: history

On July 3, 1993, there was a [baseball game](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/PHI/PHI199307022.shtml) between the Padres and Phillies that started at 1:28am and ended at 4:40am local time - [the latest finish in MLB history](https://www.mlb.com/news/the-20th-anniversary-of-the-philadelphia-phillies-and-san-diego-padres-game-that-ended-later-than-any-other-game-in-major-league-history/c-52443502). The game started so late at night because it was the second game of a doubleheader, and the first game ended very late due to 3 rain delays that added 5 hours 54 minutes of delay to the game.

On September 7, 2022, Carlos Alcaraz and Jannik Sinner played a US Open singles quarterfinal match that lasted 5 hours 15 minutes and ended at 2:50am local time - [the latest finish in US Open history](https://sports.nbcsports.com/2022/09/08/alcaraz-tops-sinner-in-latest-us-open-finish-ever/).

Has there ever been a non-baseball professional or Olympic sporting event that ended later than 2:50am local time? I am only interested in events that are held in a single stadium/arena where spectators can see the entire court/field from their seat.

Comment: When does "late" become "early"? There are plenty of endurance events (Ironmans etc) which last more than 24 hours.

Comment: I guess I will limit this question to events in a single arena. I am thinking about events where most attending fans would be expected to watch the entire event, and where such a late finish might be considered ridiculous as it may end after public transportation has closed for the night.

Comment: Le Mans 24 Hours?

Comment: I will limit this to events where all of the spectators can see the entire "playing area" from their seat (excluding obstructed view seats).

Comment: In the London Marathon (and presumably elsewhere) people are still finishing at breakfast time the following day.

Comment: There was a [Barcelona - Sevilla football match](https://www.dreamteamfc.com/c/news-gossip/198544/ronaldinho-barcelona-debut-midnight/) that started at 00.05 back in 2013, so most likely ended at around 2 am.

Answer (score 1):

The preliminaries for [UFC 257](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFC_257) *began* at 04:00, with the main card starting 07:00 local time. I don't have a finishing time, but maybe around somewhere 08:00.

You may ask why would anyone plan anything at such a strange time? The answer is of course the COVID pandemic - UFC events during the pandemic took place on [Fight Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Island) in Abu Dhabi with a limited in-person attendance, and the 04:00 to 08:00 [Gulf Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/gst) timeslot put it in prime time US viewing hours.

Comment: +1 interesting answer, although I'm not sure whether this would be considered a very late or a very early start!

Answer (score 1):

As far as events that fit my criteria, it seems it is mostly tennis matches that end beyond 4am.

According to [ESPN](https://www.espn.com/tennis/story/_/id/39336705/daniil-medvedev-plays-3rd-latest-slam-match-5-set-victory), the latest that a tennis Grand Slam match ever finished was the third-round 5-set match between Lleyton Hewitt and Marcos Baghdatis in the 2008 Australian Open - it ended at 4:34am. There was also a second-round 5-set match between Andy Murray and Thanasi Kokkinakis in the 2023 Australian Open that ended at 4:05am.

But the [latest finish ever](https://www.eurosport.com/tennis/atp-acapulco/2022/alexander-zverev-beats-jenson-brooksby-in-latest-ever-tennis-finish-at-4.55am-on-remarkable-day-in-a_sto8812400/story.shtml) in a tennis match was the first-round match between Alexander Zverev and Jenson Brooksby at the 2022 Mexican Open - it ended at 4:55am. It was only a 3-set match, but it started at 1:30am because the 2 previous matches that day ended up being the 2 longest matches in Mexican Open history.